Why is my SwiftUI View flashing a @SectionedFetchRequest with no predicate before applying the new predicate?
I am trying to populate a series of LazyVGrids with Items using a @SectionedFetchRequest in SwiftUI.
I am getting the correct results, but each time value or tag changes and composePredicate runs, there is a flash during which time the results show aa items as if there was no predicate.
and every once in a while, the new predicate in not applied and the grids show all items.
I've tried all kinds of combinations of initial and oldValue, newValue in the .onChange modifiers:
            .onChange(of: value, initial: true) {oldValue, newValue in
                withAnimation() {
                    items.nsPredicate = composePredicate(bin: bin, value: newValue)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: tag) {oldValue, newValue in
                withAnimation() {
                    items.nsPredicate = composePredicate(bin: bin, value: value)
                }
            }

What am I missing?
import SwiftUI

struct PickerGrid: View {
    
    @SectionedFetchRequest<Int16, Item>(
        sectionIdentifier: \.itemGroup,
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.itemGroup, order: .forward)]
    )
    private var items: SectionedFetchResults<Int16, Item>

    let bin: Bin
    
    @Binding var value: Int
    @Binding var tag: ItemTag
    
    @State private var showOnlyFavourites: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(items) { section in
                    VStack{
                        Text(bin.groups[Int(section.id)])
                            .font(.title2).bold()
                            .maxWidth()
                            .padding(.leading)
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 1) {
                            ForEach(section) { item in
                                Button(action: {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            tag.item = item
                                            items.nsPredicate = composePredicate(bin: bin, value: Int(tag.item.figValue))
                                        }
                                }) {
                                    ItemCell(item: item, display: .glyph)
                                        .transition(.scale(scale: 0.1777).combined(with: .opacity))
                                }
                                .contextMenu {
                                    ItemContextMenu(item: item)
                                } preview: {
                                    ItemCell(item: item, display: .value)
                                        .frame(width: item.bin == .cannedGoods ? 180 : 90, height: 90)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 12)
            }
            .onChange(of: value, initial: true) {oldValue, newValue in
                withAnimation() {
                    items.nsPredicate = composePredicate(bin: bin, value: newValue)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: tag) {oldValue, newValue in
                withAnimation() {
                    items.nsPredicate = composePredicate(bin: bin, value: value)
                }
            }
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        showOnlyFavourites.toggle()
                        items.nsPredicate = composePredicate(bin: bin, value: value)
                    }){
                        Image(systemName: showOnlyFavourites ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .padding(.trailing)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top)
                .maxWidth(.trailing)

            }
        }

    }
    
    //MARK: Constants
    
    private let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 70), spacing: 1.0)]
    
    private func composePredicate(bin: Bin, value: Int) -> NSPredicate {
        print("\nCompose predicate\n")
        let binPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "bin_ = %d", bin.tag)
        var valuePredicate = NSPredicate()
        if value != 6 {
            valuePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemValue = %d", value)
        } else {
            valuePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemValue >= %d", value)
        }
        let noGenericsPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemGroup != %d", 0)
        let onlyFavouritesPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "isFavourite == true")

        var subPredicates: [NSPredicate] = []
        subPredicates.append(binPredicate)
        subPredicates.append(valuePredicate)
        subPredicates.append(noGenericsPredicate)
        if showOnlyFavourites {
            subPredicates.append(onlyFavouritesPredicate)
        }
        
        let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: subPredicates)
        print(finalPredicate)
        return finalPredicate
    }
}

